# Add image into navigation bar

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uinavigationbar

When a item is added to favorites. I would like to indicate that it has been successfully added to the user by having a image of a star to fade in, into the navigation bar in place of the right bar button. How can I do this?

Any help will be appreciated! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can customize your right bar button item using custom button.

```
//custom back button
    button =  [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"back.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(backButtonClicked) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [button setFrame:CGRectMake(-2, 0, 52, 30)];

    UIBarButtonItem *btnItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = btnItem;
    [btnItem release];
```

Comment: Thanks for that Swastik. Would this change apply to all the view controllers or only the one I set it to. Also, would you know how I can make this button fade in. Thanks